# Content Editor in Document Set

Tags: content-type, document-set, content-editor-web-part

I have a content type based on document set type, and inside the welcome page I added a content editor webpart, however, I do not want the content of the content editor to appear in all items based on this content type, I want it to be unique per item, how can I achieve this? The other option I found was to add a noteboard, but I can't add rich text / html in a noteboard or can i?

Comment: What data do you want to display? A property on the document set? An image from the document set?

Comment: I want to have a freetext field where the user can input anything he likes / build tables / format text etc.. with a content editor they can achieve this, but then whatever they edit in one new item based on that document set, appears in all items based on that document set - and i want it unique for each item....

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve this by:

1. Create a Site Column, Multiline with Enhanced rich text (Rich text
   with pictures, tables, and hyperlinks) enabled
2. Add the document set to the document library, WITHOUT the new site column first
3. Go to the document library  > Settings > "Content Types" > "Add from existing site or list columns", then it would work and the column will be displayed as Rich Textbox when you add / edit a document in the Document Library.